# How to print value_count() values from different columns together?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset that has different columns. I have applied `value_counts()` in order to print the counts of unique values.
I have applied the same for 6 different columns as follows:

```
complete_data['Sex'].value_counts()
complete_data['Survived'].value_counts()
complete_data['Parch'].value_counts()
complete_data['Pclass'].value_counts()
complete_data['SibSp'].value_counts()
complete_data['Embarked'].value_counts()
```

I would like to know if there is a way wherein all the different columns (Sex, survived etc) can all be combined in one line of code rather than 6 different lines as above.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `for loop`:

```
for col in complete_data:
    print(complete_data[col].value_counts(), '\n')
```

Comment: I think the loop here is a good idea, storing the result for each in a dictionary where the key is the column. The `apply` version (which I like), will lead to many `NaN` cells, as most columns won't share the same values.

Answer (score 3):

```
df[['Sex', 'Survived', 'Parch', 'Pclass', 'Sibsp', 'Embarked']].apply(pd.value_counts)
```

This will give you back a df with value counts for each.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the source DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 5, 2, 1], [0, 2, 6, 7], [6, 1, 4, 6],
    [7, 0, 7, 3], [0, 3, 1, 2], [1, 5, 6, 0]], columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Then, to count `value_counts` for all columns, you can **apply**
`value_counts` to the DataFrame, actually to all columns:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

For my source data, the result is:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  2  1  0  1
1  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  1  1
3  0  1  0  1
4  0  0  1  0
5  1  2  0  0
6  1  0  2  1
7  1  0  1  1
```

i.e. `A` column has 2 cases of *0*, 1 case of *1*, *5*, *6* and *7*,
similarly for other columns.